# How to use drush download file plugin (drush_dlf) project page has no information

Tags: drush

**How to use this plugin?**

https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_dlf

> Drush Download File is a drush plugin that allows you to download files and place them in locations. This is behavior similar to what a make file can provide except you won't need to write a make file in order to get a file and put it in the right place.

This is what I am looking for, but there is not documentation, how can I do this?

I tried:

```
c:\source\sites\all\modules>drush drush_dlf
The drush command 'drush_dlf' could not be found.  Run `drush[error]
```

Not sure how to do this....

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to install the Drush extension `drush_dlf`, run:

`drush dl drush_dlf`

If the module you download is a Drush extension (has a .drush.inc file but no .module file), then Drush will put it in `$HOME/.drush`, where it will be findable by Drush.

If the module you download has a .module file, then Drush will put it in the appropriate `modules` directory (`DOCROOT/modules` for Drupal 8, or `DOCROOT/sites/all/modules` for Drupal 7). In this instance, the command will only be available for that one site.

To stipulate where the downloaded extension should go, you can add `--destination=$HOME/.drush` (or some other location). Use caution when doing this with any extension that has a .module file, though, as some of these are designed such that they only work when their module is available and enabled.

Finally, note that Drush caches the location of all of the available Drush extensions.  If you add a new extension, you must run `drush cc drush` before your new command will be available.  Drush does this automatically if you use `drush dl` to install the extension, but you must do it manually if you copy the files into `$HOME/.drush` yourself.

Finally, with regard to `Drush Download File`, the behavior it purports to provide could also be implemented with a simple shell script that simply called `drush dl` repeatedly, as Drush dl will already place the files where they belong.  Using `drush make` or `composer` is generally preferable, but just using `drush dl` directly is an option if you don't want to do that.

Comment: Am I wrong saying that Drush Download File doesn't actually work at all?

Comment: Your analysis looks reasonable, but I did not check it; I merely answered the question that was asked here. drush_dlf may or may not work correctly; if it does not, there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [plugin code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drush_dlf/tree/drush_dlf.drush.inc?h=7.x-1.x), I would say it doesn't even work.

```
/**
 * Callback for the drush-demo-command command
 */
function drush_drush_dlf_drush_download_file($type = FALSE) {

  drush_download_file($url, $destination = FALSE, $cache_duration = 0);

}
```

`drush_drush_dlf_drush_download_file()` accepts a single argument (`$type`), but then passes `$url` to [`drush_download_file()`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/includes!drush.inc/function/drush_download_file/5.x) without setting it, or defining it. It means `drush_download_file()` will get `NULL` as first parameter, but it is expecting the URL of the file to download.

As the comment for the callback says, it seems the plugin is just an example of what a plugin could do. It's not a constructive example, since it doesn't work at all.

Comment: So what commands to use to download files to put in libraries?